# requests_oauthlib cannot be imported

Tags: python, oauth

I want to access twitter apis, so requests_oauthlib is required.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
```

So, here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongo_users.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
ImportError: No module named 'requests_oauthlib'
```

But I have installed it,

```
(mongousers) root@mongobk:/home/luv/mongo_users# pip freeze
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.6
oauthlib==2.0.6
pymongo==3.6.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
urllib3==1.22
```

So, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try again! It looks like this module is only available for python 2. Perhaps your virtualenv is trying to use python3. 
If you open a python shell while in the virtual env, the version number should be visible at the top. If you don't want to use python3, you can run scripts in python 2 by typing python2 mongo_users.py